# Get the type of `flip foldr id` in Haskell from the console

Tags: haskell

How can I get the type of a function (`flip foldr id`) from theconsole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:t` command in `ghci` to find out the type of any expression.

```
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t flip foldr id
flip foldr id
  :: Foldable t => (a -> (a1 -> a1) -> a1 -> a1) -> t a -> a1 -> a1
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually in haskell there is no guesswork involved, it is best to sit down and work this with the help of the GHCi.

So let us best get started and fire up ghci

```
$ > ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a1 -> b1 -> b1) -> b1 -> t a1 -> b1
Prelude> :t id
id :: a2 -> a2
```

these are the basic types involved.

Now if we use explicit parenthization we see `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> (t a -> b)` is a function that takes a folding function and a starting value that returns a function.

Since all lower case letters on type level are (type)variables we can start to substitute

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a1 -> b1 -> b1) -> b1 -> t a1 -> b1
                        **************     **    **********
flip ::                (     a          -> b  ->    c   ) -> ( b  ->       a          ->     c      )
                                                              ***     **************      **********
flip foldr :: Foldable t =>                                    b1 -> (a1 -> b1 -> b1) -> (t a1 -> b1)
```

mind that you have inserted the first parameter of the `flip` function - therefore it does not show up in the type signature anymore.

Furthermore you can see `id` is then the starting value so `b1 ~ (a2-> a2)` so substituting that gives us:

```
flip foldr id :: Foldable t => (a1 -> (a2 -> a2) -> (a2 -> a2)) -> (t a1 -> (a2 -> a2))
```

and omitting the explicit parens again

```
flip foldr id :: Foldable t => (a1 -> (a2 -> a2) -> a2 -> a2) -> t a1 -> a2 -> a2
```

And what the great thing about this procedure - you can check every step in GHCi to see if your (equational) reasoning has been correct.

Some precautions:

- GHCi always tries to deduce the most general signature - so if you expect

  ```
  foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
  ```

then in GHC-versions later than 7.8 you will see the signature I wrote above.

- `type`-aliases might be confusing so if you have a `type MyAB a b = (a -> b -> b)` then `foldr :: MyAB a b -> b -> [a] -> b` is a correct specialization, but you probably won't see this in GHCi.